# java - How to return methods from another method - Console command interface

Tags: java, methods, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to write a console parser for a command line application and have it somehow call methods/access members of another class, to which it is not related. In my driver/main method, I create an instance of the console parser, and I pass it strings entered by the user from the console. I also create an instance of a data structure, lets say a tree, in the driver, which has specific methods and members. Obviously, any Console Parser object will not be able to call/access any of the tree's methods or members, as it is not linked to it (at least not without passing it a reference to the data structure itself). Is there anyway I can have methods in the Console parser object that say--

```
if (line.hasOption(x))
{ return thisMethod(); }
```

and then be able to simply execute whichever method is returned from the parser in the driver?

I have read about interfaces being java's workaround for passing methods as parameters, but that's not really what I'm after.

I have also looked into using a framework like Commons CLI, but want this to be a kind of 'during runtime' command interface, rather than running the program each time I want to issue a new command.

Either way, I figure I'll end up writing a lot of if/else statements somewhere, but is there a clean way to do this?

EDIT:

Ok, here's a better example:

```
    ArrayList<String> example = new ArrayList<>();

    /* PARSING */
    ConsoleParser parser = new ConsoleParser();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String parserArgs = input.nextLine();


    while (parserArgs != "quit")
    {
        execute(parser.parse(parserArgs));
        parserArgs = input.nextLine();
    }
```

So the idea is to have a console (within the application), where I can type commands like 'add x' or 'contains x' which would then be assigned to 'parserArgs.' Then the command string would be passed to the ConsoleParser where it would be dissected and searched for valid commands. If the command is valid (and has necessary options/arguments), the parse() method of ConsoleParser would somehow return the method (or name of method) to main, along with any arguments that method needs. So if I want to add the string "foo" to my ArrayList, then at the console I could type 'add foo' and that would be passed to the parser, which would then return to main some kind of instruction that the add() method of ArrayList needs to be called on 'example' with the argument 'foo.' I Know this could be easily done with an arraylist, but I just use it here for simplicity.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question. Please post a minimal example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Parser to return method name and then use java reflection for method invocation. Have you tried?

Comment: Whatever the question is, the answer will probably involve interfaces.  So please don't reject them prematurely.  (There may be ways involving reflection, but I wouldn't consider those particularly "clean", especially if you use it on names obtained from user input, which can be dangerous.)

Comment: Does Java reflection let me take a string and call the same method?

Comment: @BenGranger avoid reflection. That's not good design. Interfaces are probably the answer. If you posted an example, we could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using reflection. You can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: yes, that seems like the way I need to go, thank you